# Simple JQuery Script Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery for the first time and I am coding it by hand. But my jQuery code doesn't work at all... Here's my setup :

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="mainCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainJQuery.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="test"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**mainCSS.css**

```
.test {
    background-color:#FF0004;
    border-radius:25px;
    display:block;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
```

---

**mainJQuery.js**

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').click(function() {
        $('.test').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Working here `:)` ~> **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/y76B7/ possibly missing `<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>`

Comment: Get a tool like Firebug for Firefox.  Certainly there are errors in your javascript console that will tell you what the problem.  If I had to guess, you aren't properly including the core jQuery script.

Comment: There's no jQuery script in that code ?

Comment: Have you linked to the JQuery script?

Comment: Have you linked the jquery lib?

Comment: if you want to use jQuery.. first you need to include jQuery library. Add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>` before your script tag

Comment: I added the link Arun P Johny told me to add and it works! So, i will need to link the jQuery library every time iam using jQuery. Now I understand! THANKS! Can I put this library in my folder instead of linking it to an external server?

Comment: Just did it and it works! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to state it for the record:

**In order for your jQuery code to work, you need to link to the jQuery library in your HTML.**

If you are following a tutorial that doesn't include this in the first step, you should find another tutorial to follow.  If you got to this question because you did not follow the first step of your tutorial, you should read more carefully before falling back on StackOverflow, or risk getting some serious downvotes.

The two most common ways of including jQuery in your HTML page are:

1) Downloading the library, and linking to a local copy.  In your `<head>` section:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/url/path/to/local/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2) Linking to a remote copy of the jQuery on Google's CDN.  Again, in `<head>`:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

If you don't link to jQuery using one of those options, or something similar, your code will not work.  In most browsers you will be able to tell that this is the problem by [opening the Javascript console](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors#Step_3%3a_Diagnosis), typing "jQuery" and getting an error like `jQuery is not defined`.

It's amazing that I couldn't find a duplicate question to close this in favor of, but then again I didn't click on every single "Why doesn't this simple jQuery script work" question on StackOverflow.

And there are a lot.